# Convert two strings to float (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have some object that contains two string properties:

```
const obj = {
  a = '6',
  b = '2',
}
```

I want to get float `6.2`. What is the best and simple way?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Shouln't object properties be `a: '6'` and `b: '2'`

Comment: parseFloat(`${obj.a}.${obj.b}`

Comment: @David approach that provided below is implemented by me, but I thought it was a little rough :) anyway it works

Comment: @decpk of course you're right! :) It's just a typo but the meaning of the question does not change

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner:

```
parseFloat(obj.a + "." + obj.b)
```

Comment: alternative parseFloat(`${obj.a}.${obj.b}`

Comment: Another (weird) alternative: `parseFloat(Object.values(obj).join('.'))`

Answer (score 0):

`+(obj.a + "." + obj.b)` should work fine.

Answer (score -5):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

const obj = {
  a : '6',
  b : '2'
}

var a1=parseInt(obj.a);
var b1=parseInt(obj.b);

document.write(a1+b1/10);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You have to first convert the strings into integers.

Comment: That's just wrong in so many ways.

Comment: It returns 6.2. Can I ask why do you mean that it is wrong?

Comment: Because you cannot calculate like that. Try `0+10/10`. It is 0.1, in your example it is 1.

Comment: Both digits that the OP is using are lower than 10, so there is no problem.

Comment: Right, if you want solve a question that exactly works for a few numbers and is a way longer than the easy answer, than yes. But anyway, at least i downvoted and commented why. Have a nice day.

Comment: That is not the issue. The OP didn't state, how he intends to get the float 6.2. He only said the result, not the way of computation. We can only guess what is he computing. Therefore, any computation that leads to 6.2 is correct.